# How to apply a CSS property using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure of the code. If the height of UL exceeds 270 pixels, then I want to add the CSS property `overflow-y:scroll;` or else as it is.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

The following code uses jQuery to get the height and compare it. Note that it probably needs to be visible at the point where you call this to have a valid height.

```
$(function() {
    $(".tabs").each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.height() > 270) {
            $this.css( 'overflow-y', 'scroll' );
        }
    });
});
```

Note this will work on all elements with the class tabs, not just the first one.

Comment: Upvoted for only calling the selector once, vs the others who are forgetting basic jQuery principles.

Comment: This could be optimized by storing **var $this = $(this)** which would reduce the selector lookups by one for each iteration. +1

Comment: @caballou -- typically, that's what I would do as well.  I've updated.

Answer (score 4):

```
if($(".tabs").height() > 270) {
    $(".tabs").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
}
```

Assuming you're using jQuery.

Comment: Also assumes that there's only one mathching element on the page or that the CSS should be applied to all matching elements if the first element exceeds the height requirement...though that may be a safe assumption.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$(".tabs").attr("style", "overflow-y:scroll");
```

This will remove the current style from the element(s). You can also use the .css function referenced [here](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS). This will keep other style values.

```
$(".tabs").css("overflow-y","scroll");
```

You have to check if the height is over 270px. To do so use the `.height()` method referenced [here](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height). You need to figure out where and when you want to do this test.

Comment: Assuming he's even using jQuery, you should be using the .css() function.

Comment: that's true that works as well. I'mm adding that to my answer. He's using jquery(see tags)

Comment: thats simple :). How about checking if the `height of UL exceed 270px`

Comment: @marcgg: +1 `He's using jquery(see tags)`  correction `She`. ;)

Comment: @rakesh: My bad ^^ I also added some references to check height

Comment: Shouldn't use the `attr` function, as it could blow away existing style attributes.  Go for `css`.

Comment: maybe he wants to blow away existing style :) But that's true that she should keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Other answers give good methods to check the size. Just to add a tidbit, I prefer to keep my markup in a .css file, link that in and then apply the markup in my JavaScript file:

```
.scrollList
{
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

And then in the script:

```
$('.tabs').addClass('scrollList');
```

And if you want to remove it again:

```
$('.tabs').removeClass('scrollList');
```

And, *if* you wish to fix the size you can do that in that markup section in the .css file as well.